# Laravel Eloquent query order hierarchically

Tags: laravel, eloquent, hierarchy

Need some help in getting a collection, using Laravel Eloquent, from a table but ordered by the parent_id to achieve, as an example, the following hierarchy:

- Africa

  - Eastern Africa
  - Middle Africa
  - Northern Africa
- Asia

  - Central Asia
  - Eastern Asia

(...) etc.

The below table is what I have and it's ordered by parent_id only.

What I'm trying to achieve is the **parent** > **children** ordering. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
+----+---------------------------------+-----------+
| id | region_common_name              | parent_id |
+----+---------------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Global                          |         0 |
|  2 | Africa                          |         1 |
| 14 | Americas                        |         1 |
| 33 | Antartica                       |         1 |
|  3 | Asia                            |         1 |
|  6 | Australasia                     |         1 |
|  4 | Europe                          |         1 |
| 10 | Eastern Africa                  |         2 |
| 11 | Middle Africa                   |         2 |
|  8 | Northern Africa                 |         2 |
| 12 | Southern Africa                 |         2 |
|  9 | Sub-Saharan Africa              |         2 |
| 13 | Western Africa                  |         2 |
| 20 | Central Asia                    |         3 |
| 21 | Eastern Asia                    |         3 |
| 22 | South-eastern Asia              |         3 |
| 23 | Southern Asia                   |         3 |
| 24 | Western Asia                    |         3 |
| 25 | Eastern Europe                  |         4 |
| 26 | Northern Europe                 |         4 |
| 27 | Southern Europe                 |         4 |
| 28 | Western Europe                  |         4 |
| 16 | Caribbean                       |         5 |
| 17 | Central America                 |         5 |
| 15 | Latin America and the Caribbean |         5 |
| 19 | Northern America                |         5 |
| 29 | Australia and New Zealand       |         6 |
| 30 | Melanesia                       |         6 |
| 31 | Micronesia                      |         6 |
| 32 | Polynesia                       |         6 |
|  5 | North America                   |        14 |
| 18 | South America                   |        14 |
|  7 | Southern America                |        18 |
+----+---------------------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order by multiple conditions but have to join on yourself.

Example in SQL

```sql
SELECT rp.region_common_name parent_name, r.region_common_name FROM regions r
INNER JOIN regions rp ON r.parent_id = rp.id
WHERE r.parent_id != 1 AND r.parent_id != 0
ORDER BY rp.region_common_name ACS, r.region_common_name ASC
```

So your result will look like this:

```
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| parent_name                     | region_common_name              |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Africa                          | Eastern Africa                  |
| Africa                          | Middle Africa                   |
| Americas                        | North America                   |
| Americas                        | South America                   |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

In eloquent you can use the QueryBuilder to generate your query. 
It will look like this:

```php
DB::table('regions as r')
    ->join('regions as rp', 'r.parent_id', '=', 'rp.id')
    ->where('r.parent_id', '!=', '0')
    ->where('r.parent_id', '!=', '1')
    ->orderBy('rp.region_common_name', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('r.region_common_name', 'asc')
    ->select('rp.region_common_name as parent_name', 'r.region_common_name as name');
```